# Проблема растягивания фонового изображения.

Tags: html, css

Как сделать растягивание фонового изображения так, что-бы его высота была равна высоте страницы?

Пробовал добавлять 'background-size:cover`, результат был похожим, но изображение заполняло страницу по ширине, а не высоте, как нужно. Была идея сделать всё это джаваскриптом, но как-то нет идей, как такое осуществить.

Условное изображение того, что нужно:

[image]

Comment: `background-size: 100% 100%;` оно растянет полностю всю картинку, правда качество может пострадать)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В результате сделал всё сам, скриптом на `jquery` (`js`).

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('#mBg').width('auto');
    $('#mBg').height($(document).height());
    if ($('#mBg').width()<$(document).width())
        {
            $('#mBg').height('auto');
            $('#mBg').width($(document).width());
        }
    $('#mBg').css('left',-Math.round(($('#mBg').width()-$(document).width())/2));
});
$(document).ready($(window).resize());
```

---

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;width:100%;min-height:100%">
   <img id="mBg" style="position:relative;bottom:0" src="background.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Изображение полностью перекрывает блок, в котором содержится `div` с этим изображением, не искажая его. По-сути, это кроссбраузерная и правильно-работающая замена `background-size:cover`.

Если нужно использовать, как фон всей страницы — добавьте к стилю блока

```
position:absolute;z-index:-1
```

[Пример работы скрипта](http://amaz.3dn.ru/test.htm).

Надеюсь, кому-то это понадобится `:)`

Answer (score 0):

`repeat-y` может помочь. высоты страницы будет тянуться в зависимости от контента, а фоновое изображение будет повторяться.

Comment: проблема в том, что фон - не какая-нибудь текстура, а именно одно целосное изображение.

*извините, наверное недообьяснил суть вопроса :)*

Comment: ну а с javascript'ом у меня идея такая: проверить высоту окна. если эта высота больше, чем высота изображения - меняем атрибут `background-repeat` на `repeat-y`. @ling предложил очень хорошее решение узнать размеры окна [в этом посте][1] 
[1]:http://hashcode.ru/questions/78441/%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: @LeD4eG, повторюсь опять, изображение не должно повторятся, т.к. оно целосное, а не текстурное

Comment: @Crasher, а как вы тогда планируете свободно менять его размеры?
Ведь оно деформируется.

Comment: ой-ой)затянул с комментарием)

Comment: вообще `img` обладает таким свойством....растягивать картинку на всю свою область. именно растягивать, а не масшабировать. и вот идея в том, чтобы присваивать высоту блоку, равную высоте картинки. но это как-то.....

Comment: @Construct, в этом и состоит суть вопроса. Результат должен быть такой, как `background:... cover`, только вместо "перекрытия" ширины — высота.
<br />
@LeD4eG, была такая идея: сделать фоновый блок с абсолютной нулевой позицией, внутрь поместить изображение, а самому блоку присвоить `overflow:hidden`, но не получилсь осуществить.

Answer (score 0):

Предположу, что так, хотя не проверял.

```
<style>
body, html, #bg{height:100%}
#bg{overflow:hidden;text-align:center;position:absolute;top:0;left:0}
#bg img{height:100%}
</style>
<div id="bg"><img src="a.jpg"></div>
```

`#bg` ставится как фон, весь остальной контент имеет `position:relative;z-index:1;`.

Comment: приблизительно так же я пытался делать, но результат не тот вообще получается. Может попробовать с `min-height` и `min-width`?

Comment: А что не так получатеся?

Comment: изображение не выравнивается по центру, когда выходит за границы по широте, тоесть виден левый верхний угол.

И по широте недорастягивается, когда высота окна маленькая.

Answer (score 0):

1. А чем `{background-size: auto 100vh;}` не угодил, если нужна привязка к высоте?
2. Если использовать тег `<img>`, то все решается одним свойством css: `{object-fit: cover;}`.
3. Если по какой-то причине без скрипта не обойтись, то ваш вариант не самый лучший. Можно оптимизировать, задав так:

Псевдокод:

```
Если (высота больше ширины) {
 Приделать картинке css-класс cls1;
}
иначе {
 Приделать картинке css-класс cls2;
}
```

Стиля:

```
.cls1 {width:100%; height: auto;}
.cls2 {width:auto; height: 100%;}
```

4. Как будет выглядеть фон в вашем решении, если высота картинки будет больше ширины? ;)